# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "date_a" on code that works on 3 other pages

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, modelattribute

I have problem with this code...

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/portfolio/' + ${portfolios.getId()} + '/old' }" th:object="${Date}" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From: <input type="date" th:value="*{date_a}" th:field="*{date_a}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" th:onclick="'javascript:loading()'" value="Change day" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I really dont get why this is not working...
Its copy paste from other pages, which there are 3 of, and all the others are okey with this same snippet. But here i get error.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "date_a" (template: "portfolio" - line 12, col 42)
```

i pass an empty object on previous page with

```
ThymeDate date = new ThymeDate();
modelAndView.addObject("Date", date);
```

EDIT:

ThymeDate

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "dto_thyme")
 public class ThymeDate implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
long id;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date_a;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date_b;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public LocalDate getDate_a() {
    return date_a;
}

public void setDate_a(LocalDate date_a) {
    this.date_a = date_a;
}

public LocalDate getDate_b() {
    return date_b;
}

public void setDate_b(LocalDate date_b) {
    this.date_b = date_b;
}

public ThymeDate() {

}

public ThymeDate(LocalDate date_a, LocalDate date_b) {

    this.date_a = date_a;
    this.date_b = date_b;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please add the ThymeDate-class snippet to the question. There must be a public getter "getDate_a()" in the class to use "*{date_a}" in the template.

Comment: added. aslo it works on other pages so thats not the problem

Comment: Looks ok. You could check your model with something like <p th:text="${Date}"></p> <p th:text="${Date.date_a}"></p> before the form-element. Maybe something is going on here. Also I don't know if thymeleaf struggles to bind a not set LocalDate-field.

Comment: As stated. it works on other pages so i dont think binding empty object is problem. also Date.date_a is empty and Date prints out obect type just as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know if this about reserved keyword or something like that...
changed form object name from Date to ThymeDate and now it works?

if anyone have better explanation i can accept that as answer...